# How can I add rows to be filled from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have my code for a table that I created in html with one row, but I want to add more rows to it, the number of total rows has to be equal to the value that my combox takes (24,36,48 rows in total):

```
      <div  id="visible" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table " id="tablacondatos" name="tablacondatos">
          <thead>  
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">MES</th>
              <th scope="col">CUOTA</th>
              <th scope="col">INTERES</th>
              <th scope="col">AMORTI.</th>
              <th scope="col">CAPITAL</th>
              <th scope="col">SEGURO DESGRAV.</th>
              <th scope="col">SEGURO INMOBIL.</th>
              <th scope="col">GASTOS ADM.</th>
              <th scope="col">CUOTA FINAL</th>   
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="cuerpotabla" name="cuerpotabla">
              <tr id="filamaestra"> 
              <td id="mes" name="mes">0</td>
                <td id="cuota" name="cuota">0</td>
                <td id="interes" name="interes">0</td>
                <td id="amorti" name="amorti">0</td>
                <td id="capital" name="capital">0</td>
                <td id="segurodesgrav" name="segurodesgrav">0</td>
                <td id="seguroinmobil" name="seguroinmobil">0</td>
                <td id="gastosadm" name="gastosadm">0</td>
                <td id="cuotafinal" name="cuotafinal">0</td>   
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

This is how I get the value of my combo for the rows:

```
ahorrar =  document.getElementById("plazooperacion").value; // 24,36,48 rows
```

I am using this code to add rows, but the problem is that it generates too many rows, and in the first cells I am putting a counter, which goes from 1 to 24, or 1 to 36 or from 1 to 48; but it generates them backwards (it puts the last one first and the first one last):

```
ms=ms+1; //accountant

    var table = document.getElementById("cuerpotabla");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
     //this adds row in 0 index i.e. first place
    row.innerHTML = "<td>"+ms+"</td><td id='cuota' name ='cuota'>"+cuota+"</td><td id='interes' name='interes'>"+interes+"</td><td id='amorti' name='amorti'>"+amorti+
    "</td><td id='capital' namre='capital'>"+capital+"</td><td id='segurodesgrav' name='segurodesgrav'>"+segurodesgrav+"</td><td  id='seguroinmobil' name='seguroinmobil'>"+seguroinmobil+"</td><td id='gastosadm' namre='gastosadm'>"+gastosadm+"</td><td id='cuotafinal' name='cuotafinal'>"+cuotafinal+"</td>";
```

Comment: There is not enough JavaScript here to determine the problem.  You need to include the loop that goes through the number of rows you want to generate for us to see what the problem is.

Comment: Also you have a spelling mistake for `name` in one of the cells - `namre`

Comment: Each time you do `var row = table.insertRow(0);` it adds a new row *at the top of the table*.  try `var row = table.insertRow()` if you want the new row to be added to the bottom of the table instead.

Comment: And how can I put a limit on the rows? with the code I show

Comment: You need to use a loop, and inside that loop you put the `var row = table.insertRow()` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: And loop `ahorrar` times